# What sort of issues would I face running large numbers (hundreds, perhaps thousands) of openvpn networks on one machine?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

If, for example, one server wanted to create a separate VPN for every user on the system, that included all of their servers. There would be no internet routing, just separate VPNs between (user A and the server), and (user B and the server) etc.

Answer (score 0):

VPN software is using CPU. Most modern server CPUs have hardware acceleration units for encryption operations. The load should be similar with SSL. In the past encryption was slow. Nowdays it is not that slow compared with other operations.

As with any capacity planning you shold first read: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: I'm not overly worried about capacity or need help figuring out specs, I want more to know if I'll have technical problems. That said, would the vpn software use CPU only when it's actually communicating, or would it constantly use CPU? The scenario I am envisaging would only have maybe 2-10 of the networks transferring any application level data at any one time, and probably relatively small amounts on each network.